# How to append one deb package to Ubuntu live?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wand to append partimage.deb package to live Linux.

How to append this package to Ubuntu live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to [customize the Ubuntu Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).

Comment: which part of this link i read?

Comment: All of it. Where you're supposed to do your customisations, type `dpkg -i partimage.deb`

Comment: The whole thing, if your goal is to burn a new live CD so that when you run it, partimage is installed.  If you just want to use partimage on the Ubuntu Live cd, just install it using Applications / Ubuntu Software Center.